# If path is symlink to another path

Tags: python, filesystems, symlink

Is there a way in Python to check whether or not  a file is a symlink to another specific file? For example, if `/home/user/x` symlinks to `/home/user/z`, but `/home/user/y` links somewhere else:

```
>>>print(isLink("/home/user/x", "/home/user/z"))
True
>>>print(isLink("/home/user/y", "/home/user/z"))
False
>>>print(isLink("/home/user/z", "/home/user/z"))
False
```

(/home/user/z is the original file, not a symlink)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os
def isLink(a, b):
    return os.path.islink(a) and os.path.realpath(a) == os.path.realpath(b)
```

Note that this resolves the second argument to a real path. So it will return True if `a` and `b` are both symlinks, as long as they both point to the same real path. If you don't want `b` to be resolved to a real path, then change

```
os.path.realpath(a) == os.path.realpath(b)
```

to

```
os.path.realpath(a) == os.path.abspath(b)
```

Now if `a` points to `b`, and `b` points to `c`, and you want `isLink(a, b)` to still be True, then you'll want to use `os.readlink(a)` instead of `os.path.realpath(a)`:

```
def isLink(a, b):
    return os.path.islink(a) and os.path.abspath(os.readlink(a)) == os.path.abspath(b)
```

`os.readlink(a)` evaluates to `b`, the *next link* that `a` points to, whereas `os.path.realpath(a)` evaluates to `c`, the *final path* that `a` points to.

---

For example,

```
In [129]: !touch z

In [130]: !ln -s z x

In [131]: !touch w

In [132]: !ln -s w y

In [138]: isLink('x', 'z')
Out[138]: True

In [139]: isLink('y', 'z')
Out[139]: False

In [140]: isLink('z', 'z')
Out[140]: False
```

Comment: And if you want to find out what the symlink points to, use `os.path.realpath()`.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.

```
os.path.realpath(path)
```

Here are the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath).