# Can I ignore symlinks in setuptools MANIFEST.in?

Tags: python, symlink, software-packaging

When creating a source distribution using python's setuptools (`python setup.py sdist`), I am using a `MANIFEST.in` file containing the line:

`recursive-include mypackage`

because I want to include some non-module files inside the mypackage directory. However, there are also symbolic links under the mypackage directory whose targets I do not want included in my source distribution. Is there a way to specify "ignore symlinks" inside the `MANIFEST.in` ?

I know... I probably shouldn't have those symlinks there.

Comment: Maybe you can exclude them by running a function turning a `MANIFEST_template.in` into `MANIFEST.in` at the start of your `setup.py`? Scanning for symlinks with the info from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889368/if-path-is-symlink-to-another-path). Would be nice if there's such an option, though.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, using `recursive-include mypackage` to include everything in your package should be avoided. This can pick up lots of things you really don't want included in your distributions. You should list specific files if they are few and special, or otherwise include them by extension or other file name pattern, e.g. `recursive-include mypackage *.mydataformat`.

Comment: If you know the symlinks you can explicitly add `exclude`s after `recursive-include` in `MANIFEST.in` – directives are evaluated in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distutils does not offer any special handling of symlinks. You can look through the [`distutils` code](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/48c42eeaee4410d76675b637bcd401b8919ff19a/filelist.py?at=default#cl-187) and see that the processing of the `MANIFEST.in` file is doing simple pattern matching, using `os.listdir` recursively, without any special handling for symlinks.

Comment: You might want to edit this answer to make it clear that this means "no" to my original question -- distutils can't be told to ignore symlinks because under the hood it's not aware of them.